# How to Patch an User Model of Django with Django RF?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have UserProfile model that contains `phone`, `profile_photo` and some fields of Django default User model like `first_name`, `last_name`, `email` and I am trying to update some of these fields.

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="User")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=16, verbose_name="Phone")
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=user_directory_path, verbose_name="Profile Photo")
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(partial=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return user_profile
```

**views.py**

```
class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)

    @detail_route(methods=['PATCH'], url_path='update-partial')
    def user_profile_update_partial(self, request, pk=None):
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(id=pk)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(profile, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

If I send `profile_photo`, `phone`, `first_name` or `last_name` data with this `@detail_route` I am only able to update phone and profile_photo fields. Also getting Bad Request error when `profile_photo` data not sending.

How can I implement the `partial_update` with `PATCH` method?

Answer (score 2):

```
class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        profile = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(profile, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user_serializer = UserSerializer(profile.user, data=request.data, partial=True)
            if user_serializer.is_valid():
                user_serializer.save()
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
            else:
               return Response(data=user_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return Response(data=serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Q1:How to implement `PATCH` method?

A1:Override `partial_update` method.

Q2:How to update `first_name` or `last_name`?

A2:Update it with another Serializer named `UserSerializer`.(If you want update password,you need use `make_password` method to create encoded password before save raw password to database)

Comment: thanks for quick response. Actually I did solve that problem with [dealing with nested fields in django](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects). But now I am having trouble with updating ImageField model field. The error is: `the submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.`

Comment: You have to add your input data as formdata.